# ICE, STUN, TURN library for iOS iPhone

Tags: iphone, nat, stun, turn

I need to establish a P2P UDP and TCP Connection between two Users. Both of them are behind a NAT. A little research leads me to STUN, TURN and ICE.

1. Is there any open source iOS (library) which support the same?
2. FaceTime in iPhone also uses ICE, STUN, TURN to NAT traversal, so does iOS SDK exposes such API's?
3. I found nICRr code in resiprocate source code (www.resiprocate.org), which I am able to test on Mac OS X for STUN part. Did anybody tried using the same for iOS 4.0or above?

Thanks,
rodney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below are answer to my own queries
Is there any open source iOS (library) which support the same?
-Yes, resiprocate source code is available , it has nicer folder. it can be compiled to mac os x and ios with some efforts
FaceTime in iPhone also uses ICE, STUN, TURN to NAT traversal, so does iOS SDK exposes such API's?
- No
I found nICRr code in resiprocate source code (www.resiprocate.org), which I am able to test on Mac OS X for STUN part. Did anybody tried using the same for iOS 4.0or above?
- it can be easily recompiled to ios4

Comment: Hi Rohit, I am using https://github.com/coturn/coturn library for creating client library. can you guide me how can I build a .a or .so file from this project? I want to create a library in Mac Os from  [ turnclient ] => src / client / path in the above mentioned link.

Comment: I did it 10 years back , built the libraries for android and iOS. I took the open source and made the device specific changes to make libraries for android and iOS.

Answer (score 5):

1> use PJSIP it has all the items you request and it now builds properly on iOS

2> no

3> I dont know, but PJSIP has STUN, TURN and ICE libraries and its modular

Comment: Hi tony can you point me to some code from which i can implement turn ice and stun in ios

Comment: If you're building a commercial app you don't want to open source - PJSIP is going to cost you at least $1000. I'd recommend using reSIProcate in that case.

Comment: PJSIP 2.x no longer support video on iOS :(

Answer (score 3):

It's not open-source, but we put together a library called [IceLink](http://www.frozenmountain.com/products/icelink) that does P2P streaming using ICE/STUN/TURN with full NAT traversal. It has client SDKs for iOS, Mac, and others.